Lua pcall inconsistency while dealing with SIGINT on Linux
I am trying to understand the details of signal processing in Lua. I have a few simple one-liners that wait on something, and I interrupt them with Ctrl+C. All of them have the form print(pcall(....)).
Case 1:
▶ lua5.4 -e 'print(pcall(os.execute, "sleep 5"))'
true  nil     signal  2

The first true comes from pcall and it indicates that the call to os.execute completed successfully, but the rest of the output (the return values from os.execute) says that the call has actually failed, because it has been interrupted by the signal 2 (SIGINT).
Case 2:
▶ lua5.4 -e 'print(pcall(io.read))'
false interrupted!

Here it looks like the pcall itself has been interrupted, not io.read, but at least we get an error from pcall.
Case 3:
▶ lua5.4 -e 'print(pcall(function() for _ in io.lines() do end end))'
lua5.4: (command line):1: interrupted!
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'pcall'
        (command line):1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

Here pcall is simply ignored, and this happens each time io.lines or file:lines get interrupted. Interestingly, if I wrap this code in another pcall, then that outer pcall will behave as expected.
I generally understand the first two cases, but the last one came as a bit of a surprise to me, so my question is: are the above behaviors well-known (and I have just missed some documentation)? Also, is there anything else I have to watch out for while dealing with SIGINT?
(I have tried Lua versions 5.4 and 5.3, and they both produce the same result.)
UPDATE: Here is the comment on this issue from Roberto Ierusalimschy.

It looks like a bug, please report it on the Lua mailing list
